What counts as running a business?
Consider a hypothetical homeowners association (HOA) with deed covenants that restrict use of the property. Suppose one of the deed convents says the owner can not run a business out of his home. The owner would like to run a tutoring service. All the tutoring is done over the internet.
Would that count as running a business out of the home? Would the deed covenant would be legally binding in this case?

How would they even know, especially with the rise of working from home post-covid?

@nick012000 I do not know how they would know. Perhaps they saw an online ad. There is an enforcement issue here but that is not what I am asking about.

Generally there is context and intent to consider.  i.e. someone selling sheep out of their garage has a direct impact on the community as muddy farm trucks rolling through to pick up the wooly critters.  Doing computer work from home vs running your own enterprise would make no difference.  I trust that you know this already, but we can't provide legal advice, and can't interpret the wording of a document that isn't provided.

@MichaelHall I think what you are telling me is that there is some degree of subjective in interpreting legal contracts. As such, there is no clear answer.

Yes, but clearly written HOA rules could easily eliminate any subjectivity.  For example "manufacturing and direct to customer sales are prohibited, but online businesses that do not affect the community are allowed." What does yours say? Does it say members can't work from home, or is it a blanket prohibition against "running" a business? If so, you mentioned in an enforceability issue...

Usually HOAs are trying to avoid business where people are coming and going or there's high traffic of non-residents as the result. These covenants were written long before remote working from home was a thing.

@littleadv Also before online businesses were common.

@Bob "As such, there is no clear answer." Correct. It would be analyzed on a case by case basis with all available context to guide the court and there isn't an obviously correct answer in all cases.

@MichaelHall Let say it is a blanket prohibition against running a business in our  hypothetical case.

It was a rhetorical question.  Ohwilleke's comment above is really the answer.  The hypothetical goal should be to keep the situation out of the courts.

That’s running a business
Words in a contract take their normal meaning so, “run a business” means to engage in an activity for the purpose of commercial reward. Running a tutoring service for money is running a business; tutoring local kids for free because you’re a generous person isn’t.
As written, the contract prohibits all businesses irrespective of they can conceivably have an impact on the HOA or not. That’s fine; if they want a blanket ban they can have a blanket ban.
Unless, there is either a supervening law against unfair or unreasonable restraints of trade, or the HOA has exceeded the power given to it by the statute that controls it. Either or both is possible, but that’s not what you asked about. If that’s something you’re interested in, questions are free.

Depends on HOA regulations, and laws in your jurisdiction, particularly local zoning ordinances.
As an example, the City of Raleigh in North Carolina makes a distinction

A Home Occupation is an occupation that provides a service or product that is conducted wholly within a residential dwelling and
does not allow non-resident employees or any clients, customers,
patients, or visitors to visit the premises. Applications are no
longer required for home occupations, as defined in Section 6.7.3.D of
the Unified Development Ordinance. Although an application is no
longer required, regulations must still be followed to ensure
compliance.
A Live-Work is a commercial use that is contained within or attached
to a residential structure or contained within a legally conforming
accessory structure or accessory dwelling unit and which allows
employees, customers, clients, or patrons to visit.

The ordinance uses "occupation" to describe the first case, while the second case is clearly designated as "commercial use".

HOA rules would be additional restrictions over zoning regulations, unless the HOA has gotten an exemption from the zoning board. So what actually matters if there are local ordinances that limit what an HOA can do.

@Barmar The situation would be the CC&Rs say "no commercial use." You point out the city does not consider WFH "commercial," absent any further definition.

I don't see how local zoning laws are relevant to this question. The HOA can't violate local zoning laws, but they generally can go considerably beyond them  if they care to. Nortoriously, HOA can determine things like the allowed colors of paint for the exterior of your house. The HOA could choose to use the definition as established by city ordinances, but they are not obliged to.
